# What is proper way to handle custom validation in flask?

Tags: python, flask

Following is the method where I am handling multiple custom validation with custom messages.

```
def social_login_validation(data):
    """Login validation schema."""
    schema = Schema({
        Required('first_name'):All(str, Length(min=1, max=30)),
        Required('last_name'):All(str, Length(min=1, max=30)),
        Optional('phone_number'):All(str, Length(min=10, max=10), validate_phone_number),
        Optional('profile_picture'):Any(str, Length(min=1, max=255)),
        Optional('email'):All(str, Length(min=10, max=255), validate_email),
        Optional('auth_token'):Any(str, Length(min=10, max=255)),
        Optional('auth_token_expiry_date'):Any(str, Length(min=10, max=255)),
        Required('social_media_login_type'):All(str, Length(min=1, max=255),\
                validate_social_media_login_type),
        Required('social_id'):All(str, Length(min=10, max=255))
    })
    try:
        schema(data)
    except MultipleInvalid as error:
        if "length" in str(error) and "['first_name']" in str(error) and "at most" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['LENGTH_FIRST_NAME']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "length" in str(error) and "['last_name']" in str(error) and "at most" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['LENGTH_LAST_NAME']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "length" in str(error) and "['social_media_login_type']"\
            in str(error) and "at most" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['LENGTH_LOGIN_TYPE']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "length" in str(error) and "['social_id']" in str(error) and "at most" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['LENGTH_SOCIAL_ID']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "length" in str(error) and "['phone_number']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['LENGTH_PHONE_NUMBER']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "expected str" in str(error) and "['email']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['TYPE_EMAIL']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "data['first_name']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['EMPTY_FIRST_NAME']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "data['last_name']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['EMPTY_LAST_NAME']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "data['social_media_login_type']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['EMPTY_LOGIN_TYPE']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        elif "data['social_id']" in str(error):
            message = RESPONSES['EMPTY_SOCIAL_ID']
            code = RESPONSES_CODE['BAD_REQUEST']
        else:
            return jsonify({'message':str(error.error_message)}), 400
        return jsonify({'message':message}), code
```

What is the better way to handle these many custom messages?

Comment: This may help http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/errorpages/ . Also, if this is sqlalchemy there are custom errors for `required` columns.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using `voluptuous` package?

Instead of writing each error message yourself, you might want to use the [`humanize`](http://alecthomas.github.io/voluptuous/docs/_build/html/voluptuous.html#module-voluptuous.humanize) functionality of the package.

If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous/blob/master/voluptuous/error.py) a bit, you can see that you can access the errors by `error.errors`. I'd look a bit into that and see if you can access the errors in a way less hacky than making turning the errors into strings.

I've never used this package, but please add it to the question tags so people know what they're looking at.